# Why is Caller ID not working since 4.0.4 update on Droid 4?

Tags: google-voice, caller-id

I have a Samsung Droid 4. I keep all information about my contacts in Google Voice. In the past, this has always worked seamlessly.

However, since my phone updated it's operating system to version 4.0.4 last week, caller ID is no longer working. When people call me now, their telephone number shows up on the phone's screen. However, it doesn't match that phone number to their name from my contact list.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem? What is the fix? Why did this happen?